# How to write a Formula to have a checkbox checked by default and if the case is reopened, uncheck the box to track First Contact Resolution?

Tags: visual-workflow, formula-field, conditional, checkbox, case-object

For example, if a customer comes in and a case is created, the FCR (First Contact Resolution) Checkbox is already checked by default, then if the Case has a status of Resolved and it changes, meaning the case was reopened, can it automatically uncheck the FCR checkbox?

To simplify...
If a Case has a status of Resolved and it changes

- Check to see if FCR field is false
- If false, leave false
- If true, change to false

How would I even write a formula for this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, then you would want a regular checkbox custom field rather than a formula for FCR. And then use Before Save flow (Fast Update) to check/uncheck this custom field based on your requirement.